# TypeError while inserting data in PostgreSQL 11.0 table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert values in a PostgreSQL 11.0 table fetched from a text file using python script. One of the entry in the input file is below:

```
ENTRY       map00010                    Pathway
NAME        Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
DESCRIPTION Glycolysis is the process of converting glucose into pyruvate and generating small amounts of ATP (energy) and NADH (reducing power). It is a central pathway that produces important precursor metabolites: six-carbon compounds of glucose-6P and fructose-6P and three-carbon compounds of glycerone-P, glyceraldehyde-3P, glycerate-3P, phosphoenolpyruvate, and pyruvate [MD:M00001]. Acetyl-CoA, another important precursor metabolite, is produced by oxidative decarboxylation of pyruvate [MD:M00307]. When the enzyme genes of this pathway are examined in completely sequenced genomes, the reaction steps of three-carbon compounds from glycerone-P to pyruvate form a conserved core module [MD:M00002], which is found in almost all organisms and which sometimes contains operon structures in bacterial genomes. Gluconeogenesis is a synthesis pathway of glucose from noncarbohydrate precursors. It is essentially a reversal of glycolysis with minor variations of alternative paths [MD:M00003].
CLASS       Metabolism; Carbohydrate metabolism
PATHWAY_MAP map00010  Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
MODULE      M00001  Glycolysis (Embden-Meyerhof pathway), glucose => pyruvate [PATH:map00010]
            M00002  Glycolysis, core module involving three-carbon compounds [PATH:map00010]
            M00003  Gluconeogenesis, oxaloacetate => fructose-6P [PATH:map00010]
            M00307  Pyruvate oxidation, pyruvate => acetyl-CoA [PATH:map00010]
DISEASE     H00069  Glycogen storage disease
            H00071  Hereditary fructose intolerance
            H00072  Pyruvate dehydrogenase complex deficiency
            H00114  Fructose-1,6-bisphosphatase deficiency
            H00664  Anemia due to disorders of glycolytic enzymes
            H01071  Acute alcohol sensitivity
            H01096  Pyruvate kinase deficiency
            H01267  Familial hyperinsulinemic hypoglycemia
            H01760  Hepatic glycogen storage disease
            H01762  Muscle glycogen storage disease
            H01939  Glycogen storage disease type I
            H01945  Glycogen storage disease type VII
            H01946  Glycogen storage disease type XI
            H01951  Glycogen storage disease type X
            H01952  Glycogen storage disease type XII
            H01953  Glycogen storage disease type XIII
            H01954  Glycogen storage disease type XIV
            H01997  Pyruvate dehydrogenase E1-alpha deficiency
            H01998  Pyruvate dehydrogenase E1-beta deficiency
            H01999  Pyruvate dehydrogenase E2 deficiency
            H02000  Dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase deficiency
DBLINKS     GO: 0006096 0006094
REFERENCE   (map 1)
  AUTHORS   Nishizuka Y (ed).
  TITLE     [Metabolic Maps] (In Japanese)
  JOURNAL   Tokyo Kagaku Dojin (1980)
REFERENCE   (map 1)
  AUTHORS   Nishizuka Y, Seyama Y, Ikai A, Ishimura Y, Kawaguchi A (eds).
  TITLE     [Cellular Functions and Metabolic Maps] (In Japanese)
  JOURNAL   Tokyo Kagaku Dojin (1997)
REFERENCE   
  AUTHORS   Michal G.
  TITLE     Biochemical Pathways
  JOURNAL   Wiley (1999)
REL_PATHWAY map00020  Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)
            map00030  Pentose phosphate pathway
            map00500  Starch and sucrose metabolism
            map00620  Pyruvate metabolism
            map00640  Propanoate metabolism
            map00710  Carbon fixation in photosynthetic organisms
KO_PATHWAY  ko00010
```

Below is the section of script which creates the table, fetches the data from .txt file and insert in the table:

```
#CREATE DATABASE CONNECTION ########################

try:
    connect_str = "dbname='xx' user='xx' host='xx' " "password='xx' port = xx"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connect_str)
except:
        print("Unable to connect to the database") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

print (connect_str)

#CREATE 'table' TABLE ########################

cursor.execute("""
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table""")

try:
    cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(
            entry_id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
            id INTEGER,
            pathway_name CHARACTER VARYING,
            pathway_class CHARACTER VARYING,
            pathway_subclass CHARACTER VARYING,
            ko_id CHARACTER VARYING,

            PRIMARY KEY (entry_id))
            """)
except:
    print ("The table cannot be created")
        
with open ('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match('^[A-Z]+',line) and line.startswith("ENTRY") or line.startswith("NAME") or line.startswith("CLASS") or line.startswith("KO_PATHWAY"):
            key, value = line.split(" ", 1)
            data = key, value
            
            if data[0] == "ENTRY":
                entry = value
                id = re.findall('[0-9]+', value)
            elif data[0] == "NAME":
                pathway_name = value
            elif data[0] == "CLASS":
                pathway_class, pathway_subclass = value.split(';', 1)
                class_id = value
            elif data[0] == "KO_PATHWAY":
                ko_id  = value
                cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table (entry_id, id, pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, ko_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(entry, id, pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, ko_id))
            else:
                print ('It is a partial entry')
                
                
conn.commit()
conn.close()
cursor.close()
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The error I am getting is on line:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table (entry_id, id, pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, ko_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(entry, id, pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, ko_id))
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: In which line is the error occuring?

Comment: cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table (entry_id, id, pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, ko_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(entry, id, pathway_name, pathway_class, pathway_subclass, ko_id))

Comment: Have you tried converting `id` into an integer before passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: Use `execute` instead of `execute_many`. You only have the args for one insertion, not many